# GeoServer Max scale is too small

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system, extents

When zooming into my point layer it's just one big blob of dots. I want to be able to zoom into see individual points but scale 1:2 goes nowhere near to this extent.[image]

The layer was generated in ArcMap in GCS_WGS_1984. When I published the layer I used EPSG:32610

[image]

I computed the native bounding box from the data and Lat/Lon box from native bounds.

Answer (score 1):

I chose reproject native to declared for SRS handling. That fixed it right up.

Comment: not an answer..

Comment: It resolved the issue I was having. Thought it would help somebody else out in the future but I'll delete the post if you don't think it will be helpful or if you have something more appropriate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're assuming too much out of the layer preview, it's just meant for a quick peek at the layer, it's not a full fledged client.

Try using QGIS or a custom built OpenLayers client if you want to control the zoom ranges and the like.

Answer (score 1):

In general if you lie to GeoServer it will believe you. You told it the data was in meters when it was actually in degrees, hence you can't manage to zoom in very far. So either set reproject native to declared (or just set the declared to EPSG:4326) and everything will work out.